# BGE Character dynamic

Tags: game-engine, armature

I am making a simple game. Setting the Box to dynamic and my armature and character to static , with ghost option activated  so that it won't collide with the dynamic motion box. However , I got myself into a weird situation which had never happen before.When i  play the game , the character was standing on the floor as i wanted . But the character change its shape when i tried to move it . Walking right and left doesn't seem to be a problem but when i press w to walk infront , it flew off to the mid sky and when i press s to move backwards , it went out of shape like the picture below show. Need a solution as fast as possible. 
[image: My character went out of shape]

I tried to save the file so i could upload it here to be more specific. But after i save it and open it in another blender window . This is what i get.[image: After saving]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking my settings , i finally found a solution.
It appears that after animating my character , i didn't turn off the auto-keyframe button which is in the animating layout. Thus , when i move around my character , it automatically set location to the character meshs. Which corrupt with my armature and dynamic.So i deleted my character meshs action editor and it fixed it .
Hope this will help people who will come across this problem like me .
Remember to turn off your auto-keyframe button after you done animation. 
Cheers and have a nice day.